# Search function not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to search based on name but it's not working. Here is the code I'm using:

HTML Code for display:

```
<div ng-controller="PhoneBookUserCtrl as pu">
        <h2>User controller to get the User details</h2>
        <span>Enter name in the textbox to get details</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="pu.name" /> 
        <button ng-click="pu.get(pu.name)">Get</button>

        <p>User Information</p>
        <p><b>Name : </b> {{pu.userInfo.name}}</p>
        <p><b>Email : </b> {{pu.userInfo.email}}</p>
        <p><b>Number : </b> {{pu.userInfo.number}}</p>
</div>
```

Angular Code:

Inside Service-function for searching:

```
this.getInfo=function(name){
var info= "";
for(var i=0; i<contacts.lenght;i++){
if(contacts[i].name.indexOf(name) >= 0){
    info = contacts[i];
    console.log(info);
    break;
} else{ alert("Not found");}


}

console.log("inside getInfo");  //its getting executed

return info;

}
```

Code inside  Controller to call the function

```
app.controller("PhoneBookUserCtrl",['contacts', function(contacts){
  this.get=function(name) {
    this.userInfo = contacts.getInfo(name);
    console.log("Inside User Controller"); //its getting executed
  }

}]);
```

How can I make it work, what changes need to be done?

Comment: You have a typo in your for loop. Change lenght to length.

Comment: @itamar - Thank you very much, I got output, very good observation.

Comment: anytime :-) Glad to help.